# Is it possible to wrap promise inside generator?

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm trying to create a promise-wrapper using generator so that I can do:

```
var asyncResult = PromiseWrapper( $.ajax( ... ) );
```

So far, I've been trying with:

```
function PromiseWrapper(promise){
    return function *wrapper(promise){
        promise.then(function(result){
            yield result;
        }, function(err){
            throw err;
        });
    }(promise).next().value
}
```

but this fails because yielding inside a normal is not allowed.
Is there any work-around for this? Thank you :D

ps: I'm using babel to translate the code from es6 to es5

Comment: `yielding inside promise is not allowed` - It should have been `yielding inside a normal function is not allowed`

Comment: @thefourtheye yep that's correct-- I'll edit it now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is utterly impossible to wrap a promise in a generator that synchronously yields the promise's result, because promises are always asynchronous. There is no workaround for that, unless you throw mightier weapons like fibers at the asynchrony.

Comment: so if I use promises, then the execution gets split into 2 with one going along the original-code execution, and the other one going along the promise-execution? And yielding from the promise-execution won't do anything because the generator is expecting yield to come from the original code execution?

Comment: Yes, generators expect the `yield` in the called (resumed) code that "returns" synchronously from the `next()` method. A Promise is usually created when some background task ("asynchronous") is started, that is given a *callback* to come back later when being finished.

Answer (score 3):

Would this approach work for you http://davidwalsh.name/async-generators ?

A modified example from the link:

```
function wrap(promise) {
    promise.then(function(result){
        it.next( result );
    }, function(err){
        throw err;
    });
}

function *main() {
    var result1 = yield wrap( $.ajax( ... ) );
    var data = JSON.parse( result1 );
}

var it = main();
it.next(); // get it all started
```

You should probably read the entirety of that post, the `runGenerator` is a pretty neat approach.

Comment: There's a great article [Better Asynchronous JavaScript](http://eng.localytics.com/better-asynchronous-javascript/) explaining how to yield promises.

Answer (score -1):

```
function step1(){

    return new Promise(function(c,e){
         setTimeout(function(){
              c(`1000 spet 1`);
         },1000)
    })

}

function step2(){
    return new Promise(function(c,e){
        setTimeout(function(){
            c(`100 spet 2`);
        },10000)
    })
}


function step3(){
    return new Promise(function(c,e){
        setTimeout(function(){
            c(`3000 spet 3`);
        },3000)
    })
}


function step4(){
    return new Promise(function(c,e){
        setTimeout(function(){
            c(`100 spet 4`);
        },100)
    })
}



function *main() {
    var ret = yield step1();
    try {
        ret = yield step2( ret );
    }
    catch (err) {
        ret = yield step2Failed( err );
    }
    ret = yield Promise.all( [
        step3( ret )

    ] );

    yield step4( ret );
}

var it = main();

/*
while (true) {
    var current = it.next();
    if (current.done) break;
    console.log(current.value);
}
*/
Promise.all( [ ...it ] ) // Convert iterator to an array or yielded promises.
    .then(
        function handleResolve( lines ) {

            for ( var line of lines ) {
                console.log( line );
            }
        })
```